Change color of specific column in Excel chart with Office Scripts?
I'm trying to color a specific column on a column chart in Excel for web using Office Scripts. I'm able to set the color of all columns using this code:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("mySheet")
  const chart = sheet.getChart("myChart")
  const series = chart.getSeries()[0]

  series.getFormat().getFill().setSolidColor("red")
}

But when I try to specify a certain point with this:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("mySheet")
  const chart = sheet.getChart("myChart")
  const series = chart.getSeries()[0]

  const i = 2
  const point = series.getPoints()[i]
  point.getFormat().getFill().setSolidColor("red")
}

Then on the line const point = series.getPoints()[i] I get the error ChartSeries getPoints: There was an internal error while processing the request.
To simplify as much as possible, I've make a new workbook with only this new chart in it, using the data to its side, which still gives me the same error. Here is a screenshot of the chart.
On further testing, this does work correctly when running the script on the desktop version. This error occurs only in the browser version, which unfortunately I must use

I've tested your script on M365 without issues. Please edit your post to share a chart snapshot.

@taller Thank you, I've added a screenshot link to the bottom of my question

I’ve recreated the exact chart as yours, and the script works perfectly. I recommend creating the chart in a new workbook and testing it with a fresh OfficeScript.
